# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' ,During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, python-tesseract, modulenotfounderror

I was using pytesseract for OCR from images. Everything was working fine .. till I tried pip install pillow and pip easy install pillow in my cmd just for trying a random crop . After that when I try to import pytesseract. It keeps throwing error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 28, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pytesseract
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .pytesseract import ALTONotSupported
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 30, in <module>
    import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Python 3.9 version. Pillow is compatible with that but only from v8. Check your pillow version. If its below 8, update it using:

`>>pip install --upgrade Pillow`

Moreover, if the 2nd error still persists, try this:

`from PIL import Image`
instead of
`import Image`

Comment: Thanks bro . I uninstalled pillow first and went with >>pip install --upgrade Pillow . Now its solved

Comment: @Rahul Ramesh Glad to know it solved your problem....consider an upvote if you found it helpful so as to help more people notice it. See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-search-highlighting-accepted-answers-stack-overflow/226447/&ved=2ahUKEwj8oPfn2ZjuAhXG7XMBHXXYAy0QFjAUegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw10PcO6nqxDX39n_DBOe1Jn